# Wiindows 8 app using Salesforce Mobile SDK

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk

Can I use the salesforce mobile sdk to build windows 8 app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Mobile SDK currently supports the following approaches

- Native iOS
- Native Android
- Hybrid iOS
- Hybrid Android

Although it uses Cordova for packaging which does support Windows 8 development, the support for being able to run your app as a WebView in Windows 8 is not provided in Mobile SDK. If you are developing a Salesforce app for Windows 8, you should instead look at either of the following approaches

- Native and use [Force.com Toolkit for .NET](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET)
- Go hybrid and [use AJAX Toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 Apps are not mobile apps, so I wouldn't expect the mobile sdk to be of any assistance. More importantly, Salesforce1 mobile doesn't install on a PC running Windows 8 as a Windows 8 App. Salesforce runs from a browser in Windows 8, just like it does in any other version of Windows.